# how to create new component dynamically use eval in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

how to create a new component instance use eval?

```
import { SampleComponent } from '/path/to/component';

export class AppComponent {
    var component_name = 'SampleComponent';
    var object = eval(`new ${component_name}`); // <----- ERROR ReferenceError: SampleComponent is not defined
    var object = new SampleComponent;           // <----- OK
}
```

Comment: hi can u please tell more what you trying do

Comment: You cant do that with eval :)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader  try this guide